# how to recieve a trigger with collider or recieve a trigger with collider in unity

Tags: unity, collision-detection

i know if your object has a Collider you can sense another Collider with OnCollisionEnter function or... and you can sense another collider with trigger with OncollsionEnter function and...
but i want to sense other object with trigger even with collider or even with trigger. i cant sense otherobjects that have triggers. for example i have bullet that as i dont want to collider have any physics i turned it to trigger but how can make a charcter to sense it?

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more than simple, but remember you must have attached rigidbody on either object.

Second is *tag*. It is one of the many ways to detect any specific object through tag. Create a specific tag by selecting any GameObject from hierarchy, in inspector click on tag drop down and add a new tag, for example **bullet**. Set the tag of your bullet to the newly created one, i.e. **bullet**

Now I'm assuming that your character have rigidbody attached then you can detect through script attached to your character by,

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if(collider.gameObject.tag == "bullet") // this string is your newly created tag
    {
        // TODO: anything you want
        // Even you can get Bullet object
        GameObject strikingBullet = collider.gameObject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[You should read this documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

There is this image here you can use as a reference:

[image: Collision Matrix]

Comment: I have a target that is Kinematic Rigidbody with a trigger collider, and a bullet which is a non-kinematic Rigidbody with a regular collider, and it doesn't work. However, I have the targets moving up and down, and they do report collisions with the ground.